# How admin access link without logging in

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Can anyone give me solution for this issue (or article, keyword ): 
One user create a product, and back-end will be send mail for admin to approve the product, this mail has contained the link:
http://localhost:11260/#/productHandle/116796
I want admin don't need login in system, and can access this link.

because the current code in Global.asax check cookies:

```
protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     HttpCookie ck = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
     if (ck != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(ck.Value))
     {
         FormsAuthenticationTicket fat = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(ck.Value);
         UserProfile profile = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserProfile>(fat.UserData);
         MyPrincipal myPrincipal = new MyPrincipal(profile.Username);
         myPrincipal.UsrProfile = profile;
         HttpContext.Current.User = myPrincipal;
     }
 }
```

---after access successfully, i intended to encrypt this link. but step above don't work..
thank for help me!

Comment: can you see this cookie in the debugger of chrome for instance?

Answer (score 0):

We have a similar application that involves a user requesting access to our document imaging system, and then an email is sent to our application admins for approval.  The general idea looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult RegisterNewUser(NewUser model)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    var pwSalt = repository.CreateSalt();

    var newUser = User();
    newUser.Username = model.Username;
    newUser.Email = model.Email;
    newUser.PasswordSalt = pwSalt;
    newUser.Password = repository.CreatePasswordHash(model.Password, pwSalt);
    newUser.IsApproved = false;
    newUser.RegisterDate = DateTime.Now;

    db.Users.Add(newUser);
    db.SubmitChanges();

    ConfirmationEmail(model.Username);

    return RedirectToAction("RegistrationSuccess");
  }
}
```

The above code is the post-action for a new user who's just registered for our application.  It adds the user to the db table.  The model contains fields like name, username, email, etc (I also have a function "CreatePasswordHash" which uses the user's password and a generated SALT to created an encrypted password).  One thing to note is that the Users table contains a column "IsApproved", which sets to "false" by default.  Without this value changing to "true", the user won't be able to use the application.  Within this action is another function named "ConfirmationEmail" which is where we send an email to one of the admins for approval.

```
public void ConfirmationEmail(string username)
{
  var user = db.Users.Single(u => u.Username == username);

  string mailBody = "A new user requires approval for document imaging.\n\n"
    + "Name: " + user.Name + "\n\n"
    + "\n\n"
    + "If you approve, follow the link below: \n\n"
    + "http://example.com/Imaging/Account/Approval/" + user.UserId;

  MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
  msg.Priority = MailPriority.High;
  msg.To.Add(admin@example.com);
  msg.Subject = "New User registration approval";
  msg.Body = mailBody;
  msg.IsBodyHtml = false;

  SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
  smtp.Send(msg);

  msg.Dispose();
}
```

The above function takes a username param from the original registration action, which we use to find the user record (note: Username in the Users table is a UNIQUE column, so it will fail validation if it's not unique).  I create the body of the email using plain text, and attach the URL of the approval action for the admin to confirm approval.  Everything else is standard mail code (SMTP settings are stored in my web.config file).

Account controller -- Approval action:

```
public ActionResult Approval(int id)
{
  var user = db.Users.Find(id);
  user.IsApproved = true;

  db.SubmitChanges();

  EmailApproval(id);

  return View(user);
}
```

Simple action that changes the "IsApproved" flag to true, which grants the user access to the application.  The View that is returned contains basic user information displayed in a nice confirmation window.  Lastly, there's a function "EmailApproval" which sends an email to the user about being approved.  It uses the same emailing practices as the other function above.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can make action insecure ([[AllowAnonymous]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.allowanonymousattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) will help you) and implement security for this action via IP address.

In this case you need to implement you own Authorization filter (read [there how to do it](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-custom-action-filters)) and check that it is called from predefined admin's IP and call is local (use [HttpRequest.IsLocal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.islocal%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for checking this).

Frankly, **I never will do something insecure in my projects** so you have to think twice before doing something similar for this.

From other hand you can extend your session timeout.